# Using radio buttons to show content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The purpose of this is to have text show in the placeholder div upon selecting the radio button. Problem is my Jquery coding is bad, and In don't know what I'm doing really.

html

```
<div>
<form>
<input id="one" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="first">Radio Button here
<input id="two" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="second">Another Radio button
<input id="three" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="third">Yet another radio button
</form>
</div>

<div class="placeholder">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.menu').click(function () {
        if ("#one").checked {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3>');
        }if ("#two").checked {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing  Testing</h3>');
        }if ("#three").checked {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
        }
    });

});
```

Note: if I check all three radio buttons at once, I am wanting all three messages to come up. I notice in JSfiddle, I can only click one radio button at a time. If I click another it unchecks the previous button. I am using similar code on the website im working on at the moment, and it allows me to check as many as I want. Reasoning for this?

Website Im working on using radio buttons - http://bitlamp.wctc.edu/~kschmelzer/js2/LLC/

I am trying to have have options be checked, through three different "pages" (note if the site doesn't load, the "pages" are merely divs being hidden/shown on the button press. It's all on one page) using the next button, then on the final fourth page, it shows content (the text) from the selected radio buttons.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The purpose of radio buttons is that you check only one. So the behaviour in your JSfiddle should be correct. Since you use different forms in the different "pages" like you discribe, you can select multiple or all of the radio buttons. But maybe you should use check boxes if you want to select multiple options.

Comment: Check boxes are probably the way to go, thank you for the heads up. I will change that!

Comment: also if you change the `name` attribute of the radio buttons not to be the same it will still allow you to choose more than one of them

Answer (score 1):

There's some sintax errors, see there: http://codepen.io/FuckingLunatic/pen/grvZyd

```
$('.menu').click(function () {
        if ($("#one").is(":checked")) {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3>');
        }if ($("#two").is(":checked")) {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing  Testing</h3>');
        }if ($("#three").is(":checked")) {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why ? What is wrong with the code OP has provided ? How your code is different from the one OP has provided ?

Answer (score 1):

added the updated version of your code , check it

```js
    $('input:radio[name=option]').click(function () {
    $('.placeholder').html();
        if ($(this).val() == 'first') {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3>');
        }if ($(this).val() == 'second') {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing  Testing</h3>');
        }if ($(this).val() == 'third') {
            $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<form>
<input id="one" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="first">Radio Button here
<input id="two" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="second">Another Radio button
<input id="three" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="third">Yet another radio button
</form>
</div>
<div class="placeholder">
</div>
```

Comment: Why ? What is wrong with the code OP has provided ? How your code is different from the one OP has provided ?

Comment: If condition is not Proper  if ("#one").checked

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.menu').click(function () {
      var text = '';
      switch( this.id ) {
        case 'one': text = 'Selected: one';
        break;
        case 'two': text = 'Selected: two';
        break;
        case 'three': text = 'Selected: three';
        break;
      }
      $( '.placeholder' ).html( text );
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="one" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="first">Radio Button here
   </div>
  <div>
<input id="two" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="second">Another Radio button
  </div>
  <div>
<input id="three" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="third">Yet another radio button
  </div>
</form>
</div>

<div class="placeholder">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $('#one, #two, #three').change(function(event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'first') {
      $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3>');
    } else if (value == 'second') {
      $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing  Testing</h3>');
    } else if (value == 'third') {
      $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
    }
  })


});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input id="one" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="first">Radio Button here
      <input id="two" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="second">Another Radio button
      <input id="three" class="menu" type="radio" name="option" value="third">Yet another radio button
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="placeholder">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all radio buttons let user select ONE of a limited number of choices, if you would like to create a multi-select field you might want to use

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Radio buttons are treated as group based on their name field, so you can make a workaround and use unique names for each of the options - but that's definitely an example of a bad practice.

As for the code

```
if (one.checked) {
  $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3>');
}
if ($("#two").prop('checked')) {
  $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing  Testing</h3>');
}
if ($("#three").is(':checked')) {
  $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
}
```

You can perform check if input is checked either using checked property or via jQuery is(:checked) or prop

You can find working version here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pcor7khq/1/

Answer (score 0):

First, to fix radio button behavior you have to put  them all in one `<FORM>`  tag with the same name.

Second, you probably don't need jQuery here at all. Just use CSS selector

```
input:checked ~ .message{display: block}
```

See my example here 
https://jsfiddle.net/sewy1w71/

Answer (score 0):

It would be more easy if you are choosing check box instead of radio button..
I think the following code will results your output..Try it

```
<form id="group2">
<input id="1" class="menu" type="radio" value="first">Radio Button here
<input id="2" class="menu" type="radio" value="second">Another Radio button
<input id="3" class="menu" type="radio" value="third">Yet another radio button
</form>

<div class="placeholder">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var marray = [];
    $('.menu').click(function () {      
        if ($("#1").is(":checked")){
            var found = jQuery.inArray('1', marray);
            if (found < 0)
            marray.push('1');
        }

        if ($("#2").is(":checked")){
            var found = jQuery.inArray('2', marray);
            if (found < 0)
            marray.push('2');
        }        

        if ($("#3").is(":checked")){
            var found = jQuery.inArray('3', marray);
            if (found < 0)
            marray.push('3');
        }

        var a = marray.sort().toString();
        switch(a)
        {
            case '1'     : $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3>');
                           break;
            case '2'     : $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing  Testing</h3>');
                           break;
            case '3'     : $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
                           break;            
            case '1,2'   : $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3><h3>Testing  Testing</h3>');
                           break;
            case '1,3'   : $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3><h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
                           break;
            case '2,3'   : $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing  Testing</h3><h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
                           break;
            case '1,2,3' : $('.placeholder').html('<h3>Testing</h3><h3>Testing  Testing</h3><h3>Testing Testing Testing</h3>');
                           break;
            default      : $('.placeholder').html('');
                           break;                                                   

        }        
    });

});

function remitem(arr, value) {
    var b = '';
    for (b in arr) {
        if (arr[b] === value) {
            arr.splice(b, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
</script>
```

check the fiddle..
https://jsfiddle.net/rcvk9Ldw/